# Amazon EC2 error IOError Input/Output cada 6 o 12 Horas

Tags: python, django, ec2

Al poner mi proyecto en Amazon EC2, me paso que interactuando con mi aplicación en un momento salio el error de

```
errno 5 input/output error django
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Encontré [este ticket reportado](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23284)

En mi consola me apareció que mi servidor requería reiniciarse, y cuando lo hice, y volví a iniciar mi aplicación (gunicorn y nginx) todo se arregló mágicamente.

Este error me apareció  ayer y hoy de nuevo.
El traceback es este:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/accounts/profile/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django_extensions',
 'storages',
 'userprofile']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/neurorehabilitation-system/userprofile/mixins.py" in dispatch
  7.         return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in get
  157.         context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/neurorehabilitation-system/userprofile/views.py" in get_context_data
  50.             print (user.is_physiotherapist)

Exception Type: OSError at /accounts/profile/
Exception Value: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

A lo último en la línea 50 se referencia una función mía `get_context_data()` la cual pertenece a una vista basada en clase que hereda de `TemplateView`

Me atrevería a pensar que esto no tiene nada que ver con el error, dado además de que en mi entorno de desarrollo nunca pasó nada.

```
File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/neurorehabilitation-system/userprofile/views.py" in get_context_data
  50.             print (user.is_physiotherapist)
```

Pero en un inicio si coincide con lo que describe el ticket que comparto.

Cuando un bug es declarado como invalido en Django, ¿esto que significa?
Si me voy por la lógica, uno pensaría que el bug es totalmente obsoleto o que no tiene validez ... Pero no se que pensar.

¿Es posible que haya algun problema a nivel de la infraestructura IaaS de EC2 con Django (cosa que no creo pues estamos hablando de empresas gigantes) o mas bien sería mi aplicación?

Comment: El problema en el ticket que mencionas era al imprimir un archivo XML, posiblemente no había espacio en disco o alguna situación especifica del IO, ¿puedes agregar la traza del error? y al menos la porción del código que provoca el error

Comment: Si, estaba viendo que el traceback de ese ticket es algo específico de su aplicación, concretamente el xml que referencias, y tal vez por eso fue que el ticket fue cerrado en la plataforma. Mi error no alcancé a registrarlo, pero intenté reproducirlo examinando el comportamiento de mi aplicación haciendo cosas parecidas a lo que hice cuando salió y nada.  Solo que me despistó un poco, pues pensaba que si fue publicado como ticket tipo "issue" en django, pudiera ser un problema o del framework como tal o de la plataforma ec2 en relación a este. Pero esto no era nada lógico.

Comment: ¿Es una instancia t2.micro gratuita?

Comment: Si, si lo es. ¿Tiene algo que ver?, nuevamente me apareció el error hoy, pondré el traceback y una imágen editando mi pregunta, para que se vea

Comment: He estado buscando y en este post a esta persona le sucede algo similar (no con el mismo error) pero si manifiesta que reinicia su server y se arregla todo ...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083103/aws-ec2-t2-micro-instance-very-unstable

Allí una respuesta habla de mirar la parte de autoescalamiento (aunque creo que es para su error) y chequear politicas de health de la instancia, pero pienso que mi proyecto hosteado es lo suficientemente pequeño como para no molestar por estas cosas ...

Comment: en esta pregunta pasa algo similar (no menciona que fuera en EC2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409897/ioerror-input-output-error-when-printing y comentan el espacio, me surge la duda, ¿el error ocurre cada determinado tiempo? ¿la apllicación tiene permiso para el IO de la instancia de Amazon? ¿si hay espacio disponible?

Comment: @KristianDamian en efecto es algo similar, y creo que la causa de mi error era lo siguiente: En el traceback que muestro arriba en mi pregunta, en mi función `get_context_data()` en la linea 50. tengo una sentencia `print` la cual pensaría que cada vez que se dispara o entra en acción este print, escribe al stdout de m instancia en EC2, pero no acabo de comprenderlo muy bien. El caso es que eliminé ese print y todo funciona perfecto. Por otro lado tengo que quitar el DEBUG=True de producción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He estado detallando mi código y tengo que decir que la causa de este problema de input/output estaba allí.

He cometido dos errores de novato :(

1. **Tengo una sentencia** `print` **en producción**

En el traceback que he mostrado arriba en mi pregunta, en mi función `get_context_data()` tengo esto:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/neurorehabilitation-system/userprofile/views.py" in get_context_data
  50.             print (user.is_physiotherapist)
```

Esta función `get_context_data()` se ejecuta cada que mi usaurio inicia sesión en el sistema, es posible que cada vez que el `print (user.is_physiotherapist)` es ejecutado, este proceso intente escribir algo al archivo stdout de mi maquina en EC2, aunque es algo que no acabo de comprender o dimensionar del todo

He eliminado esta sentencia print, hice commit y push a mi repositorio, y en mi server recupere esos cambios y reinicie mi servidor gunicorn y todo funcionó perfectamente.

2. **Tengo** DEBUG=True **en producción**

Para mis settings tengo la siguiente jerarquía de archivos:

```
settings/
    base.py --- SIN DEBUG
    development.py --- DEBUG=True
    testing.py --- DEBUG=True
    production.py --- DEBUG=False
    staging.py --- DEBUG=False
```

Todos los archivos (`development.py, testing.py, production.py, staging.py`) heredad de `base.py`

Pero no se como hacer para que mi maquina en EC2 que es mi servidor de producción, tome `base.py` y despues ejecute `production.py` y sobreescriba el `DEBUG` a `False`

[En este post](https://nicksergeant.com/automatically-setting-debug-in-your-django-app-based-on-server-hostname/) se establece el valor de `DEBUG` (`True` o `False`) según el nombre de host de la maquina en donde corre mi aplicación Django.

En mi caso en mi instancia E2, este es el valor de mi hostname

```
(nrb_dev)ubuntu@ip-172-31-27-249:~$ python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> a=socket.gethostname()
>>> a
'ip-172-31-27-249'
>>> 
>>> if a != 'ip-172-31-27-249':
...     DEBUG = print ('Caleno juiciocito')
... 
>>> DEBUG
True
>>>
```

Esto significa que en mi archivo `base.py` colocaría:

```
import socket

if socket.gethostname() == 'ip-172-31-27-249':
    DEBUG = False
else:
    DEBUG = True
```

Mi inquietud, es que estoy "hardcodeando" el hostname de mi maquina en producción por lo que estoy introduciendo un punto que se deberá modificar manualmente cuando la maquina de producción a utilizar no sea la misma

¿Es esto una buena práctica a pesar de que funciona?
Pensaría que no, pero cualquier aporte en este sentido es bienvenido.

Porque otra opción que tengo es configurar el valor de la variable de entorno de `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`

En mi caso, estoy utilizando `virtualenvwrapper` y tengo dos entornos virtuales:

nrb_dev para desarrollo en donde tengo un hook en `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/postactivate` asi:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="neurorehabilitation.settings.development"
```

De la misma manera, en mi entorno virtual `nrb_test` tengo este hook

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="neurorehabilitation.settings.testing"
```

Esto quiere decir que en mi maquina en produccion simplemente cambio este hook en `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/postactivate` asi:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="neurorehabilitation.settings.production"
```

Y al hacer la prueba (imprimi el valor de DEBUG de manera temporar en mi archivo `settings/production.py`) veo que esta establecido DEBUG a False

```
(nrb_dev)ubuntu@ip-172-31-27-249:~/workspace/neurorehabilitation-system$ gunicorn -c neurorehabilitation/gunicorn_config.py neurorehabilitation.wsgi 
[2016-01-08 00:26:15 +0000] [6691] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
[2016-01-08 00:26:15 +0000] [6691] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (6691)
[2016-01-08 00:26:15 +0000] [6691] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-01-08 00:26:15 +0000] [6694] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6694
False
^C[2016-01-08 00:26:19 +0000] [6691] [INFO] Handling signal: int
```

Creo que esta segunda opción de modificar la variable de entorno de DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE en mi maquina en producción es mejor, pero cualquier aporte o consideración al respecto es bienvenido.

**Notas adicionales**

Si quisiera llevar un registro de sucesos en mi aplicación, puedo explorar [la funcionalidad de logging de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/)

Debo explorar el servicio de [supervisor](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html#supervisor) para administrar de una mejor manera el servidor WSGI de gunicorn.
Algunos recursos interesantes en este sentido son:

[How to install and manage supervisor in Ubuntu and Debian](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps)

[Setting up Django with Nginx, Gunicorn, virtualenv, supervisor and PostgreSQL](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/)

Comment: Que bueno! El tutorial de Michal me sirvió mucho también, lo encontré hace ya tiempo